# Cancelled NSOperation EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash when setting isFinished

Tags: ios, objective-c, exc-bad-access, key-value-observing, nsoperation

I have an `NSOperation` subclass that runs async operations from a `UITableView`.

I override the correct start and finish methods like this:

```
- (void)start
{
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
    self.isExecuting = YES;
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];

    if (self.isCancelled)
    {
        [self finish];
        return;
    }
}
- (void)finish
{
       if (!_isExecuting)
        {
            [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
            _isExecuting = YES;
            [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
        }

        [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
        [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];

        _isExecuting = NO;
        _isFinished = YES;

        [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
        [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
}
```

The problem I have, it if I scroll down the table and delete a row, this calls the `cancel` method on the operation, however as the operations gradually complete and it reaches further down the table, it crashes with an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error on the line `[self didChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];`

The code is pretty complex to paste it all here, but what i'd like to know is how can I track down what object is causing the KVO message to crash?

If I enable zombie objects in the debugger, it simply doesn't crash at all with no warnings which doesn't help.

If I wrap the KVO methods in `try/catch` it is never caught and still crashes.

I have tried overriding the KVO methods in my `NSOperation` subclass, but they are never called:

```
- (void)addObserver:(NSObject *)observer forKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptions)options context:(void *)context
{
    NSLog(@"%s - %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, observer);
    [super addObserver:observer forKeyPath:keyPath options:options context:context];
}
```

Is it possible to see who the observers are?

Comment: Did you find an answer for this problem, did your remember?

Answer (score 3):

Comments and ideas:

1. In `start` shouldn't `self.isExecuting = YES` be `_isExecuting = YES;`?
2. Add a property called `identifier`of type NSString, and set it for each op.
3. Add a `dealloc` method and log the `identifier`.
4. In `finish` test for `isCancelled` and return immediately if so.

Another thought is to doubly retain the operations - put them in a NSDictionary with the `identifier` as the key, and see if anything changes.

Comment: 1, thanks changed. 2&3 I used `indexPath` and deleted indexPath 4-14 which cancelled and dealloc'd the `NSOperation` immediately. Just after the operation queue finished indexPath 4-9 it crashed. From my understanding of the Apple docs, even cancelled operations get started then finish. So it must be trying to start 4-14 but as it's been dealloc'd I don't see how it can crash on the finish method.

Comment: Its been a long time since I used NSOperations - I switched to GCD as soon as it came out. Why didn't you try 4? Its possible you trying to change properties after cancelled is causing problems...

Comment: I think I have fixed it, and it's related to 4. In my cancel method I was manually calling the finished method. I'm sure I read somewhere to do this as the cancel method is simply just flipping `isCancelled` bool. Removing that seems to have stopped the crash

Answer (score 2):

I met with the same problem.
It occurs because you set the value for the isFinished variable before the-start method is called.

To solve this problem you need to set the flag isCancelled = YES (and only) in the-cancel method.
And in the method -start to do a check on the state of cancellation.

If the operation was canceled before it started, then you should already set these values:

```
    self.executing = YES;
    self.executing = NO;
    self.finished  = YES;
```

All code:

```
-(void)start
{
   if ((self.ready == YES) && (self.executing == NO) && ((self.finished == NO)) // if Ready To Start State
  {
    self.ready = NO; self.executing = YES; self.finished = NO; // Setting  Working State

    [self receiveItemAtURL:self.url params:self.params
           timeStoreExpire:self.storageTime
                  progress:self.operationProgressBlock
                completion:self.operationCompletionBlock];

  }else if ((self.ready == NO) && (self.cancelled == YES){ // If Cancelled State
    self.executing = YES;
    self.executing = NO;
    self.finished  = YES;
   }
}


- (void) cancel
 {
    if ((self.ready == YES) && (self.executing == NO) && ((self.finished == NO))      { // If Working State
    self.ready = NO; self.cancelled = YES; // Setting Cancelled State
     }
    else if ((self.ready == NO) && (self.executing == YES) && (self.finished == NO) || // If Working State
         (self.ready == YES) && (self.executing == NO) && (self.finished == NO))   // If Suspend State
   {
    self.state = RXCOCancelled;
    self.executing = YES;
    self.executing = NO;
    self.finished  = YES;
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue on MacOS and realised it is caused by setting `isFinished` on an operation that has been cancelled, which will then remove it from the queue immediately, but out of turn.

Given there is a check for `isCancelled` inside the `start` function, there is no need to set `isFinished` when you cancel.

Instead, your `start` will take care of that and the queue will remove accordingly.

You should also check for `isExecuting`

```
override func start() {
    isExecuting = true
    isFinished = false
    guard !isCancelled else {
        finish()
        return
    }

    if let willStart = exportProgress.willStartQueuedOperation {
        willStart()
    }
}

func finish() {
    isExecuting = false
    isFinished = true
}

override func cancel() {
    super.cancel()
    if isExecuting {
        finish()
    }
}
```